# How do I fix the broken Windows 7 Search feature?

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-home-server, .ds-store

I'm trying to search my Windows Home Server for `.DS_Store` files that my Mac littered the server with. Windows 7 reports there are no `*.DS_Store` files in a folder, even though I can see it with the `Show hidden files and folders` option turned on. What can I do to track all these files down on my server and wipe them out?

Comment: but... there ARE not *.DS_Store files, surely? I do not believe * matches `nothing`.

Comment: If he had a mac, I'd bet a good sum that there was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Window's "Search Advanced Query Syntax", which basically lets you do stuff that Vista and XP advanced search used to let you (that Windows 7 hid). Read about it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/advquery.mspx).

You can just search `filename:.DS_Store` to find all files with a file name that begins with ".DS_Store". Should work.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of this. I even have an Ars Technica article starred in Google Reader about the Advanced Query Syntax. :facepalm:

Comment: :) that's good.

Comment: You've got link rot. Does anyone know where to get the link about advanced query syntax